# Chrome: how to hide Chrome's page paint time panel in the top right corner?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Any option to show/hide the black box in the top right corner of Chrome when you open Developer Tools ?

Comment: Here it is: http://imgur.com/wvFHAMw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle for this is called **Enable continuous page repainting** and is located in the Developer Tools' drawer, under the Rendering tab.

[Chrome Developer Tools Rendering Settings](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings)

[image: Enable continuous page repainting]